# How to align the top row properly, I tried a few different things not working... image given below

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

.KV code part

```
MDGridLayout:
    cols: 4
    adaptive_height: True
    #md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

    MDIcon:
        halign: "center"
        icon: 'magnify'
        pos_hint: {"x": .00}
        size_hint: 

    MDTextField:
        id: symbol_field
        hint_text: " Search by STOCK KEY"
        pos_hint: {"x": .05}
        on_text_validate: root.Pressed()
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: ""

    MDIconButton:
        halign: "center"
        icon: "arrow-right-thick"
        pos_hint: {"x": .90}
        on_press: root.Pressed()

    MDIconButton: #new
        halign: 'center'
        icon: 'cog'
        pos_hint: {'x': .95}
        on_press: root.settings()
```

The weird alignment not able to change it [The top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQL2.png)

It should be like:
'label' [0-0.05] 'text-field' [0.05-0.90] 'button' [0.90-0.95] 'button' [0.95-1]

Comment: Will there be more rows in the `MDGridLayout`?

Comment: nope, this is GridLayout inside another larger GridLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, it is not using MDGridLayout (the nature of the Grid, alingment is really hard to do), in this example I am using FloatLayouts plus BoxLayouts plus canvas:

```
Screen:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: [0,0,0,.1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    #START
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1.4}
            padding: dp(15)
            #Control the background here jbsidis
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,1,1,1]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos[0],self.pos[1] #-dp(15)
                    size: self.size[0],dp(80)
                    radius: [dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8)]
                    #source: "jbsidis_background.png"
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": 1.0}
            size_hint: .8,None
            spacing: dp(3) 
            MDIconButton:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .25}
                halign: "center"
                icon: 'magnify'  
            FloatLayout:
                BoxLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_y": .5}
                    MDTextField:
                        id: symbol_field
                        hint_text: " Search by STOCK KEY"
                        #on_text_validate: root.Pressed()
                        required: True
                        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                        helper_text: ""
                    MDIconButton:
                        halign: "center"
                        icon: "arrow-right-thick"
                        #on_press: root.Pressed()
                    MDIconButton:
                        halign: 'center'
                        icon: 'pencil'
                        #on_press: root.settings()
```

Here is the image (the one in the left side):
[image]